# finding maximum from partial string

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a list where first 6 digit is date in format yyyymmdd. The next 4 digits are part of timestamp. I want to select only those numbers which are maximum timestamp for any day.

```
20160905092900
20160905212900
20160906092900
20160906213000
20160907093000
20160907213000
20160908093000
20160908213000
20160910093000
20160910213100
20160911093100
20160911213100
20160912093100
```

Means from the above list the output should give the below list.

```
20160905212900
20160906213000
20160907213000
20160908213000
20160910213100
20160911213100
20160912093100
```

Comment: Assuming the input is always in increasing time order, what you want is the record just before each change in the first 8 characters (the day), right? Use substr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{
   dt = substr($0, 1, 8)
   ts = substr($0, 9, 12)
}
ts > max[dt] {
   max[dt] = ts
   rec[dt] = $0
}
END {
   for (i in rec)
      print rec[i]
}' file    

20160905212900
20160906213000
20160907213000
20160908213000
20160910213100
20160911213100
20160912093100
```

We are using associative array `max` that uses first 8 characters as key and next 4 characters as value. This array is being used to store max timestamp value for a given date. Another array `rec` is used to store full line for a date when we encounter timestamp value greater than stored value in `max` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$  sort -r file | awk '!seen[substr($0,1,8)]++' | sort
20160905212900
20160906213000
20160907213000
20160908213000
20160910213100
20160911213100
20160912093100
```

If the file's already sorted you can use `tac` instead of `sort`.